# Excel VBA Issue

Tags: vba, excel

Using the following code to auto upper two columns,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C5000", "P3:P5000")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
               Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Works perfectly, the problem is, if a user selects multiple cells, and hits delete, it errors, then the user hits End and the function no longer works. protected. Run-time error 13, type mismatch.

Doesn't matter if the cell is empty or not, still get the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @ScottHoltzman solves the issue of the current problem, where an error is raised when you apply `UCASE` to an `Array`. When the `Target` range has more than one cell its `.Value` is an array, and `UCase` does not accept an array parameter.

Your routine will exit this line (`.Value = UCase(.Value)`) and will miss the next line that resets `Application.EnableEvents = True`. After that, you end up working with events disabled, so all your event handling routines will stop working, not only this one (in case you had other such routines).

To avoid these situations the good approach is to implement proper error handling in event handlers, following this structure

```
Sub my_Handler()
  On Error Goto Cleanup
  Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' etc..

 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 '
 ' normal code of the routine here
 '
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Cleanup:
  if Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
  Application.EnableEvents = True, Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' etc..
End Sub
```

To apply it to your routine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' etc..

    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:P5000")) Is Nothing) Then
        Target.value = UCase(Target.value)
    End If

Cleanup:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then msgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' etc..
End Sub
```

Importantly, don't use this structure automatically for all you routines, only `Event handlers` or eventually macros ythat you would invoke from the GUI. Other routines are usually called from these handlers or macros, so you can write them normally.

Answer (score 0):

Account for multiple cells this way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C5000", "P3:P5000")) _
      Is Nothing) Then

        Dim rCell as Range
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For each rCell in Target
            rCell.Value = UCase(rCell.Value)
        Next

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Using those code gets me "Invalid or unqualified reference at the

rCell.Value = UCase(.Value)

line. If I changed it to UCase(Target.Value), ends up the same type mismatch error.

Comment: @BenLogan - I edited. I forget to place rCell.Value.

Answer (score 0):

If they are selecting multiple cells then my thinking is that you would want to use SelectionChange macro instead, like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

 StartTime = Timer


    If ((Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Or _
    Target.Address = Target.EntireColumn.Address)) Then Exit Sub


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C5000", "P3:P5000")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        On Error GoTo endItAll
        For Each aCell In Target.Cells
           Range(aCell.Address) = UCase(Range(aCell.Address))
        Next aCell
    End If
endItAll:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Debug.Print SecondsElapsed
End Sub
```

Or you could change it back to the worksheet_Change macro like below and it will not error if the user selects multiple cells or deletes cells without causing an error.  The error handler is there - Like in A.S.H. 's solution, but I haven't yet seen it needed in my testing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C5000", "D1:D5000")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        On Error GoTo endItAll
        For Each aCell In Target.Cells
           Range(aCell.Address) = UCase(Range(aCell.Address))
        Next aCell
    End If
endItAll:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: While this works, after a mass deletion of say 50 lines, the user has to wait for Excel to do its thing (iterate through the 50 selected cells).

Comment: How long does that take?

Comment: Deleting lines does not trigger the WorkSheet_Change subroutine.

Comment: @Ben Logan, I've changed the Worksheet_SelectionChange code to ignore reacting when rows are being deleted so there is no time loss when the user deletes row.  I selected 1000 rows, which took .03 seconds, and deleting entire rows did not take anytime.  Deleting 500 words from each column at the same time did not take anytime at all.  But selecting those thousand words took .05 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting this in a comment to the answer, but was too long, so sorry..
@a-s-h @a.s.h
This one worked the best, with a slight modification. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' etc..

    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C5000", "P3:P5000")) Is Nothing) Then
        Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    End If

Cleanup:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo EndLine
EndLine:
   Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' etc..
End Sub
```

Performs uppercase, and deletes multiples at once without any errors, or MsgBox's.

Comment: Ben, the only difference with my answer is that you dropped displaying the error message. While this is occasionally ok, I dont recommend it for the general case, because I suggested a "general" error handling mechanism and it is important to notify the user when something went wrong, otherwise (s)he could think that all was OK and eventually miss some work. Apart of that, the lines `EndLine` and the one above it can be erased from your code, they do nothing. :)